# How to store Outlook emails data into database using ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, outlook-restapi

I have to store outlook emails data which triggered to my organization email id like Sender id, recipient id, email body and attachments in a SQL Server database using ASP.NET Core.

Can you please suggest how to do it? I checked same the thing on google didn't got expected result.

Comment: **(1)** Find a .NET Core compatible library to access Outlook e-mails, **(2)** design a suitable table (or multiple tables) in SQL Server to hold the data, **(3)** implement the reading out and storing of the e-mails. The question is waaaaaaaaaaaay to broad - therefore, any answer will be as well .....

Answer (score 0):

You could try below steps to store the outlook email in the sql database by using asp.net core:

1)Use Microsoft Graph API to access Outlook emails.Go to the Azure portal and register your application to get the client ID and secret.

2)Use OAuth 2.0 to authenticate your application and request access to the user's Outlook account.

```
var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
    .Build();
```

3)With the access token, make requests to the Graph API to fetch emails.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
{
    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}));

var messages = await graphClient.Me.Messages
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

4)Create SQL Server database and tables which stores email data, senders, recipients, and attachments.

5)Install Entity Framework Core and use it to store your data in the database.

```
public class EmailContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    // Other DbSet properties for senders, recipients, and attachments
}

public class Email
{
    public string SenderId { get; set; }
    public string RecipientId { get; set; }
    // Other properties for the email body and attachments
}
```

Note: Handle any sensitive data securely, in compliance with your organization's policies and any relevant data protection regulations. Make sure that any sensitive data is encrypted and that you're following best practices for securing your application.